# Transaction not showing up in transactions list

Tags: python, transactions, coinbase-api

A transaction shows up on my Coinbase transactions list online, and it also shows up when querying for it directly via the python api:

client.get_transaction(account_id, transaction_id)

However it doesn't show up in transactions list amongst other transactions when I do:

client.get_transactions(account_id)

Any clue what's going wrong? I'm using the official python api v2.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, turns out I had more transactions than expected -- needed to paginate or set limit=100. Couldn't figure out how to paginate just yet on the python api, so instead ended up setting the limit.